# Passing a event as an argument into a method

Tags: c#, events

I want to pass an event into a method. The code I have is as follows, but what do I put for the type "XXX" ?

```
internal class Retriever<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Retriever( XXX event, EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler )
    {
        _event = event;
        _handler = handler;

        _event += handler;
    }

    XXX _event;
    EventHandler<TEventArgs> _handler;
}
```

**Edit**:  Elaboration of the question. I'm trying to write a generic event guard, where the event is subscribed to prior to an event occurring, and unsubscribed after the event has occurred.  This class would look like:

```
internal class EventGuard<TEventArgs> : IDisposable where TEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
    public Retriever( XXX event, EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler )
    {
        _event = event;
        _handler = handler;

        _event += handler;
    }

    XXX _event;
    EventHandler<TEventArgs> _handler;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _event -= _handler;
    }
}
```

and I would use it the following way. `Proxy.RetrieveAsync` is a web method, which upon completion would cause the `Proxy.RetrieveCompleted` event to be fired.  The body of the completion handler `HandleRetrieveCompleted`, which is not shown, would call Set() on the ManualResetEvent (passed in as the UserState object).

```
using ( new EventGuard<EventArgs>( Proxy.RetrieveCompleted, new  EventHandler<EventArgs>( HandleRetrieveCompleted) ) )
{
    ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent();
    Proxy.RetrieveAsync(resetEvent);
    resetEvent.WaitOne();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't - an event is like a property, it's just syntactic sugar around a pair of methods (add/remove instead of the get/set for a property). F# actually *does* expose events as first class citizens, but C# doesn't :(

There are a few options though:

- Pass in an "event subscriber" delegate that you call with the new handler you want to add (and potentially an event unsubscriber delegate too). Something like this:

  ```
  new Receiver(handler => button.Click += handler, ...)
  ```
- Pass in an `EventInfo` and subscribe with reflection (urgh)
- Look into the Reactive Extensions framework, which has various ways of working with events (using reflection, but it means Microsoft does the reflection work rather than you :)

We could give better advice if we knew the bigger picture - care to inform us more?

EDIT: Okay, so in this case you'd need to pass in both the subscription and unsubscription code:

```
using (new EventGuard<EventArgs>(h => Proxy.RetrieveCompleted += h, 
          h => Proxy.RetrieveCompleted -= h,
          HandleRetrieveCompleted))
{
    ...
}
```

That's pretty nasty, admittedly. You may well find there's something nicer in [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx), but that would at least work...

Comment: I've edited the question to give more context of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: ugh, this combined with the fact that multiple classes can't publish the same event, plus events using strong-references *(the #1 cause of memory-leaks in C# programs)*, plus the **incredibly** unnecessarily verbose syntax they use *(have to manually check for nulls on every call?  Really!?)*... I think events need a complete rework for C# 5.0

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I think the same about the code verbose, and there are more problems and limitations about a .NET event. To solve this things, or at least have a good alternative I write some code that can be useful, please check this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/864690/Simplifying-Events-in-NET for more information.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The null conditional operator in C# 6 makes the null checking simpler: `Click?.Invoke(this, args)`.